# What can I use to create a program which can use an online connection (in python)?

Tags: python, tkinter, server, client

I really apologize for the poorly worded question but I can't think of a better way to word this in one sentence.

Basically, I am starting my programming project which will be a team management software. I will be making the GUI for it with tkinter and it will have a number of features but having started to plan it out I release there is a number of things I don't know how to do.

The main thing I'm really having trouble planning out is notifications. When someone sends a message or sets a task, other users who are related to it will need to receive a live notification and be able to see it straight away. Specifically what I don't know how to do is create a connection between multiple clients where they can all be sent messages and also I don't know how I would listen for a message and run code when it is received in a tkinter program.

I don't have any experience doing anything like this so if the question is too long winded to answer I would really appreciate if someone could maybe suggest some methods or tools I could use or point me to some good documentation.

Thanks and again sorry for the somewhat convoluted question.

Comment: Read up on the python `socket` library. Here is a short blog post about it : https://www.pubnub.com/blog/socket-programming-in-python-client-server-p2p/

Comment: First I would say break down your question into easy to read sections ( I did this for you to give you an idea of what I mean ). A wall of text is a pain to read. Second what you are asking is not a specific question but several. If I were you I would simply start building your GUI and functions and when you get stuck then with your code you have post a question including that code and ask a specific question related to the issue you ran into at that time. Then continue working until the next problem you cannot solve and ask another question. Rinse and repeat.